# Oracle SQL - Find instances of a value within a group

Tags: oracle

All,

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Event_id     Event_Rank     Procedure     Modifier
--------     ----------     ---------     --------
1             1.01          12345         AA
1             1.02          12345         AB
1             1.03          67890         ZZ
2             2.01          12345         AA
2             2.02          67890         ZZ
```

I am trying to run an Oracle SQL Query that finds within a group (Event_ID), any instance where there are 2 of the same procedures.  For Event 1, that does exist (the first two line)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

TonyVan

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
  with w_data as (
        select 1 event_id, 1.01 event_rank, 12345 c_procedure, 'AA' modifier from dual union all
        select 1 event_id, 1.02 event_rank, 12345 c_procedure, 'AB' modifier from dual union all
        select 1 event_id, 1.03 event_rank, 67890 c_procedure, 'ZZ' modifier from dual union all
        select 2 event_id, 2.01 event_rank, 12345 c_procedure, 'AA' modifier from dual union all
        select 2 event_id, 2.02 event_rank, 67890 c_procedure, 'ZZ' modifier from dual 
        )
  Select event_id, event_rank, c_procedure, modifier
    from (
           select event_id, event_rank, c_procedure, modifier,
                  count(*) over (partition by event_id, c_procedure) dup_chk
             from w_data
          )
  where dup_chk > 1
  /

    EVENT_ID EVENT_RANK C_PROCEDURE MO
  ---------- ---------- ----------- --
           1       1.01       12345 AA
           1       1.02       12345 AB

  2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Perfect!  It gave me the exact result I was looking for.